# I am trying detect circles from a image using Hough Transform in OoenCV

Tags: python, opencv3.0, hough-transform, canny-operator

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time 
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)

ccimg=cv2.Canny(img,100,100)
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",ccimg)

image=cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
cv2.imshow('Canny[enter image description here][1]',image)


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=50,param2=30)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
print circles
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So basically what i am trying to do is i am reading a image and transforming it to canny image and then i am using that canny image as **Hough Gradient** Parameter..

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: as i am using canny it is clearly visible there there exist 3 circles but the no. of circle detected is too many ...